# I want to keep blinking the led till i give the input for next colour to blink?

Tags: arduino

QUESTION -
Create a program so that when the user enters “B” the green light blinks, “g” the green light is illuminated “y” the yellow light is illuminated and “r” the red light is illuminated.
The above question is about controlling LED blinking with the help of Arduino , am personally doing the simulation on tinkercad.

[image]

ARDUINO CODE -

```cpp
char mychar;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.println("Enter which colour you want to Blink\n1.'b' for green colour \n2.'g' for yellow        colour\n3.'r' for red colour");

    while(Serial.available() >= 0)
    {
        mychar = Serial.read();
        if (mychar == 'b')
        {
            digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
            delay(100);
            digitalWrite(7, LOW);
            delay(100);
            digitalWrite(8, LOW);
            digitalWrite(9, LOW);
         }
         if (mychar == 'g')
         { 
             digitalWrite(7, LOW);
             digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(8, LOW);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(9, LOW);
             break;
          }  
          if (mychar == 'r')
          {
              digitalWrite(7, LOW);
              digitalWrite(8, LOW);
              digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
              delay(100);
              digitalWrite(9, LOW);
              delay(100);
          }
    }
}
```

I tried to use while loop instead of if condition but it keeps blinking the LED even if i gave a different colour LED input.
After  giving  the first input I want compiler  to  keep executing that command(i.e. keep LED blinking with that colour) until I give the next input .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

- Update `mychar` only if input from serial port is available.
- Write signals to ports even when input from serial port is not available.
- Add indentation to your code for better readability.

Fixed code:

```cpp
char mychar;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  // you may need this only once (per reset)
  Serial.println("Enter which colour you want to Blink\n1.'b' for green colour \n2.'g' for yellow        colour\n3.'r' for red colour");
}

void loop()
{

  // use if instead of while
  // don't execute when Serial.available() == 0 (remove = from the condition)
  // put only the reading statement in the body
  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
    mychar=Serial.read();
  }



  if(mychar=='b')
  {
    digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(7,LOW);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);


  }
  if(mychar=='g')
  { 
    digitalWrite(7,LOW);
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);
    // no break here because here is no longer inside while
  }

  if(mychar=='r')
  {
    digitalWrite(7,LOW);
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
    digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);
    delay(100);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on what was my mistake in the code  logic ?

Comment: @Sam. Your code is doing `mychar = Serial.read();` in every iteration. `Serial.read()` returns `-1` when no data is available, so the LEDs won't blink unless the characters are supplied from the serial port for each iteration.